# How do I setup my computer to run multiple sessions at once with different peripherals?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, multiple-monitors

I have built another computer for my organization, but it is so powerful that I put it in an office where multiple people are sitting next to each other.

I have several monitors, and that gave me an idea: could I somehow setup this machine to run multiple desktop environments at once and display each one on a different monitor? Also, could I set up a certain keyboard and mouse to work only on a certain screen? If these are possible, how would I do it? I was hoping that I would be able to do this without using the network for VCN or anything of the such, but I am still open to it.

In other words, I want to use one computer to act as multiple computers, with multiple monitors and multiple pairs of mice and keyboards.

Comment: It is called "multi-seat". https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiseatTeam/Instructions https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/936873/linux/-howto-multiseat-with-ubuntu-16-04-systemd-gdm-proprietary-drivers/ https://plus.google.com/+ScotStevenson/posts/QXbTpcUjfji